# Which site is best for asking questions about Android tablets?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Questions like (with additional added detail and context, of course):

> Why does my tablet charge slowly?

or

> Why does my tablet often hang?

Which Stack Exchange community would be appropriate for these types of questions, if they were fleshed out with suitable additional details?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

We've a site called [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) it takes many kinds of Android questions, although questions about Android development are explicitly off-topic there.

- There is a [charging](/questions/tagged/charging) tag and [a number of questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/charging) written by people with various problems charging their Android device.
- There's also a question about [diagnosing hanging](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3081/how-do-i-diagnose-hanging-and-restarts) so perhaps you should start with that before asking any other hanging questions.

Here's a [link to the help centre](https://android.stackexchange.com/help) so you can see what kind of questions would be on-topic.